# Not receiving messages sent to websocket through redis pubsub

Tags: websocket, redis

I have create a websocket server which subscribe to Redis Pubsub in the backend
when user logs in he will be alloted to channel by the name of path
example **ws:localhost:8000/<channel_id>**.
But the data sent to pubsub is to received to particular user.

Dictionary to store WebSocket clients and their corresponding paths

```
connected_clients = {}

async def websocket_handler(websocket, path):
    # Extract the path from the URL (e.g., /user1)
    user_path = path.strip('/')
    print(f"New WebSocket connection with path: {user_path}")

    # Connect the client to the specific Redis channel based on the path
    redis_channel = f"channel:{user_path}"
    print(f"User '{user_path}' connected to Redis channel: {redis_channel}")

    # Add the client to the dictionary of connected clients with their path
    connected_clients[websocket] = redis_channel
    
    try:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Received WebSocket message from path '{user_path}': {message}")
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print(f"WebSocket connection with path '{user_path}' closed.")
    finally:
        # Remove the client from the dictionary when the connection is closed
        del connected_clients[websocket]

def subscribe_and_send_to_websockets(redis_host, redis_port, redis_password, websocket_port):
    # Start the WebSocket server in a separate thread
    start_server = websockets.serve(websocket_handler, '0.0.0.0', websocket_port)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

    # Connect to Redis
    redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, db=0, password=redis_password)

    while True:
        # Wait for incoming connections
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

        # Subscribe to each connected client's specific Redis channel
        for websocket, channel in connected_clients.items():
            if channel not in redis_client.channels:
                pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()
                pubsub.subscribe(channel)

                # Listen for messages in a separate thread
                def message_handler():
                    for message in pubsub.listen():
                        if message['type'] == 'message':
                            data = message['data'].decode('utf-8')
                            print(f"Received message for path '{channel}': {data}")

                            # Send the message to the connected WebSocket client
                            asyncio.run(send_to_websocket(websocket, data))

                # Start the listening thread for the specific channel
                thread = threading.Thread(target=message_handler)
                thread.daemon = True
                thread.start()

def send_to_websocket(websocket, message):
    try:
        print(f"Sending message to WebSocket client: {message}")
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocket.send(message))
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print("WebSocket connection closed while sending a message.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    redis_host = 'localhost'
    redis_port = 6379
    redis_password = 'password'
    websocket_port = 5000  # Choose any available port for WebSocket server
    subscribe_and_send_to_websockets(redis_host, redis_port, redis_password, websocket_port)
```